# Symfony2 return value of flush metode

Tags: php, symfony

Ok i got stuck and no info in documentation about this (correct me if i am wrong)

Example: i have update metod in controller, some form and if forim is valid i use flush method to make changes. How can i check if changes were made in DB so i can send flash message if changes were made "Success" or if query is not executed if there is some error i send flash message "Failed to make changes to DB"

Here is example of my code but i think that flush returns  void or null so this is not the way to go, maybe it returns some exceptions on failure i dont know..

```
/**
 * @Route("createpost", name="createpost")
 */
public function createPostAction(Request $request) {
    if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }
    $post = new Post();

    $form = $this->createForm(new PostForm(), $post);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $author = $user->getUsername();

        //$post->setPublishDate(new \DateTime);
        $post->setAuthor($author);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $pom = $em->flush();
        return $this->render('success/success.html.twig', array(
           'test' => var_dump($pom)
        ));
        if($pom) {
            $this->addFlash(
                'notice',
                'You have successfully created post'
            );

        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home', array(), 301);
    }
    return $this->render(
        'create/post.html.twig', array(
           'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: I have used return $this->render... and var_dump on $pom which store returned value of flush method and got null, than i have found where flush method is defined under doctrine vendor... and in anotations i saw it returns void so i cant use it to check if changes were actually applied to DB... Is there another way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
...
if($form->isValid()) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $author = $user->getUsername();

    //$post->setPublishDate(new \DateTime);
    $post->setAuthor($author);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($post);
    $em->flush();

    if(null != $post->getId()) {
        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'You have successfully created post'
        );

        return $this->render('success/success.html.twig', array(
            'test' => var_dump($pom)
        ));

    }

    // This line never be called
    return $this->redirectToRoute('home', array(), 301);
}
...
```

However, you don't need to check if flush worked properly or not, it throws an exception if something goes wrong..

**Update for the comment:**

```
if($form->isValid()) {
    try {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $author = $user->getUsername();

        //$post->setPublishDate(new \DateTime);
        $post->setAuthor($author);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        if(null != $post->getId()) {
            $this->addFlash(
                'notice',
                'You have successfully created post'
            );

            return $this->render('success/success.html.twig', array(
                'test' => var_dump($pom)
            ));

        }
    } catch (SOMEEXCEPTION $e) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home', array(), 301);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i wanted to handle that myself not symfony.. i know it  throws an exception but in that case i want redirect to form again with some flash message,

Comment: @Constantine1001 Use `try catch` block then.

Comment: yea, i've already tried that.. 
try {
         $em->persist($page);
         $em->flush();
         $this->addFlash(
                    'warning',
                    'Bravo'
                );
         } catch(Exception $message) {
                $this->addFlash(
                    'warning',
                    $message
                );
         }

But symfony throws his default exception which is (i guess) layer below mine, so it cant do..

Comment: I can't say this my complete answer to your question. This is just an idea.. May be [this](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) can help you, i don't know..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    return $this->render('success/success.html.twig', array(
       'test' => var_dump($pom)
    ));
    if($pom) {
        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'You have successfully created post'
        );

    }
```

To

```
    if($pom) {
        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'You have successfully created post'
        );

    }
    return $this->render('success/success.html.twig', array(
       'test' => var_dump($pom)
    ));
```

You need to add flash before returning the response

Comment: Thanks for help but i have used that return only to check what flush method returns and as i said above flush method returns void or null which i have found where method is defined under doctrine -> vendor... and in anotations it say flush method returns void... Maybe it throws some exception if changes are not applied to DB ?